# two closed sets $A, B$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$ and $A \cap B \not= \emptyset$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We know that $\mathbb{R}_+$ is connected. Suppose that I find two nonempty closed sets $A,B$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $ \mathbb{R}_+ \subseteq (A \cup B)$. Then, can we say that $A \cap B \not= \emptyset$?

I think that this is true, but I am struggling with the proof. I was trying to proceed by saying that suppose that $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and I was hoping to reach the result that $\mathbb{R}_+$ is disconnected, which is a contradiction. Can you give some suggestion?

Comment: Why cannot it be that $A = B = \mathbb{R}_+$?

Comment: What is you definition for a subset to be connected? That it can't be the disjoint union of two open subsets? If that is, consider $\bar A = \mathbb R_+ \setminus A$ and $\bar B = \mathbb R_+ \setminus B$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Oh...  I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, providing that you suppose that none of $A,B$ is empty. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If $A \cap B=\emptyset$, $\bar A = \mathbb R_+ \setminus A$ and $\bar B = \mathbb R_+ \setminus B$ would two open subsets of $\mathbb R_+$ with empty intersection whose union would be $\mathbb R_+$. A contradiction  as $\mathbb R_+$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is connected iff we cannot write $X = C \cup D$ where $C,D$ are both closed and disjoint and non-empty.

So if $A,B$ are closed and non-empty in $\Bbb R^+$, which is connected, then if they cover $\Bbb R^+$ (i.e. $\Bbb R^+ \subseteq A \cup B$) they cannot be disjoint so indeed $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ follows.